# Why is Zelinsky believed when he says he felt no pressure?

Tags: united-states, trump-impeachment

One of the Republican defenses against a possible quid-pro-quo is that Zelinsky did not feel any pressure. We know this because [he said he did not feel pressure](https://edition.cnn.com/videos/tv/2019/10/01/lead-clarissa-ward-3p-live-jake-tapper.cnn). But, why do we believe this statement of his? Of course he felt pressure - the President of the United States, one of the most powerful countries in the world was asking him to do something. If he gets on the US's bad side, it could be very bad for him. The US gives Ukraine tons of money in military aid - besides for any other positive effects that may result from having a world super power on your side. So, why do we take Zelensky's word when he says he wasn't pressured?

Comment: This might be a duplicate of: [Why is the fact that Ukraine President Zelensky publicly stated that Trump didn't pressure him whatsoever being ignored?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/q/47009/19301)

Comment: @divibisan I guess they are kind of similar but from completely opposite sides. I'll look further to check if the answers answer my question.

Comment: @Burt Yeah, that's why I didn't vote to close, but they do seem to be getting at a very similar issue. Maybe edit your question to highlight the differences.

Comment: @divibisan I looked more at the other question. I would say because my question is coming later than the other one, things have happened - like public trials and Zelensky giving more interviews to leading papers. So, the circumstances have changed - changing the question.

Comment: Would any ruler of any country even  *admit* that they feel pressured?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Republicans are taking the role of Trump's defense, not judges, or investigators.

One of their bigger problems is that they have no defense witnesses. Everyone who could give testimony that supports [one of the many](https://www.washingtonpost.com/politics/2019/11/18/defenses-trumps-allies-have-floated-ukraine-impeachment/) defenses offered has [been forbidden by the Trump administration](https://www.nytimes.com/2019/11/12/us/politics/mulvaney-impeachment-subpoena.html) from testifying, or been [dismissed as irrelevant](https://edition.cnn.com/2019/11/11/opinions/republicans-want-to-call-hunter-biden-democrats-should-call-ivanka-trump-obeidallah/index.html) by the Democrats.

Because they have no witnesses, they need to get whatever they can. A statement by the president of the Ukraine that he didn't feel pressured is better than nothing.

Democrats have specifically countered that defense through [witness testimony (warning: autoplay video!)](https://edition.cnn.com/2019/11/18/politics/ukraine-zelensky-pressure-trump-investigations/index.html) that contradicts Zelensky - who did not speak under oath, had reasons to avoid antagonizing Trump, and whose words [may have been mistranslated](https://www.washingtonpost.com/politics/2019/11/22/why-ukraines-president-said-thered-been-no-pressure-trump/).

Comment: Why then do the democrats play along with that?

Comment: @Burt Do they? I don't know that anyone but Trump's defenders consider Zelinsky a reliable source for this.

Comment: @divibisan in that case I stand corrected. I was under the impression that other's considered it credible as well.

Answer (score 2):

> So, why do we take Zelensky's word when he says he wasn't pressured?

The Democrats in the House Intelligence Committee don't say that; they claim he was pressured.

Their report describes the pressure put on Ukraine repeatedly, based on testimony and evidence. I will quote directly from [the report](https://intelligence.house.gov/uploadedfiles/20191203_-_full_report___hpsci_impeachment_inquiry_-_20191203.pdf) (emphasis mine; selective quotes, see report for full context):

> In his public testimony, Ambassador Sondland testified that the President’s
>   direction to withhold a presidential telephone call and a White House meeting for President
>   Zelensky were both quid pro quos designed to **pressure** Ukraine to announce the
>   investigations.

> On October 17, at a press briefing in the White House, Acting Chief of Staff Mick
>   Mulvaney confirmed that President Trump withheld the essential military aid for Ukraine as
>   leverage to **pressure** Ukraine to investigate the conspiracy theory that Ukraine had interfered in
>   the 2016 U.S. election.

In their *key findings of fact*, which shows how the report characterizes the efforts as *pressure*.

> II In furtherance of this scheme, President Trump—directly and acting through his agents
>   within and outside the U.S. government—sought to **pressure** and induce Ukraine’s
>   newly-elected president, Volodymyr Zelensky, to publicly announce unfounded
>   investigations that would benefit President Trump’s personal political interests and
>   reelection effort.

> V President Trump used the power of the Office of the President and exercised his authority
>   over the Executive Branch, including his control of the instruments of the federal
>   government, to apply increasing **pressure** on the President of Ukraine and the Ukrainian
>   government to announce the politically-motivated investigations desired by President
>   Trump.

> VI (...) In fact, the President sought to **pressure** and induce the government of Ukraine to
>   announce politically-motivated investigations lacking legitimate predication that the U.S.
>   government otherwise discourages and opposes as a matter of policy in that country and
>   around the world.

Finally, they had a witness, Mr. Holmes, testify the Ukrainians did feel the pressure. Again from the report:

> By the time of the inauguration, Mr. Holmes assessed that President Zelensky and the
>   Ukrainians were **already starting to feel pressure** to conduct political investigations related to
>   former Vice President Biden.